# Extract report results with CloudConnect

Tags: gooddata, cloud-connect, cloveretl

I would like to extract raw report results within the CloudConnect process.

So far I have managed to get response from the raw report API end point - `https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/app/projects/{project_id}/execute/raw/`

This response contains URI to the file and if I put that URI to browser, file is uploaded.

I have tried passing this URI to the following readers without success:

- **CSV Reader** produces the following error:

> ------------------- Error details ------------------
>
> Component [CSV Reader:CSV_READER] finished with status ERROR.
>   Parsing error: Unexpected end of file in record 1, field 1 ("date"),
>   metadata "outOfStock";
>   value: Raw record data is not available, please turn on verbose mode.

- **File Download** - I don't know how to pass the URI through the port to "URL to Downlaod" parameter.
- **HTTP Connector** again I don't see how to pass URI from the port.

What is the way to do this?

**EDIT**

If I use the **HTTP Connector** as suggested by @Filip, I get the following error:

> Error details:
>   Component [HTTP connector:HTTP_CONNECTOR] finished with status ERROR.    hostname in
>   certificate didn't match: xxx.com != secure.gooddata.com OR secure.gooddata.com

I have tried setting header to `X-GDC-CHECK-DOMAIN: false` with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from GoodData support:

> HTTP connector can be also used, but it is very complex, because
>   logging in to GoodData has to be created. REST connector has it built
>   in.
>
> If you want to run the example graph, you have to be logged in in
>   CloudConnect with a user who has access to the project from where you
>   would like to export the report. You also have to change URL to
>   the one of white-labeled account in both REST connector components and change project
>   and report definition in the first REST connector.

So the graph that works looks like this:

[image: Graph that loads report]

Here are the main fields that you will need to set for each element:

1. **Get Results URI** - set params for POST request:

`Request URL = https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/app/projects/${GDC_PROJECT_ID}/execute/raw/`

`Request Body = 
   {
  "report_req": {
    "reportDefinition": "gdc/md/${GDC_PROJECT_ID}/obj/${OBJECT_ID}"
  }
}`

2. **Get URI from Response** - just map **uri** value to corresponding field:

   `<Mapping cloverField="uri" xpath="uri"/>`
3. **Load Results** - make sure it is connected to metadata with two fields, one for response with data, other to pass through the `uri`.
4. **Load Results** - you will need to exclude `uri` field to process the data:

`Exclude Fields = uri`

Answer (score 1):

The **HTTP connector** is the right component to go with. Leave the URL property empty and use the component’s property called “**Input mapping**”, where in the graphic editor you can assign the input edge field to the URL field.